# Why symbol rate equal to bit rate despite the fact that the transmission scheme use 5 bit per symbol?

Tags: digital-communications

I am practicing Digital communication (Baseband demodulation/Detection) when I encounter this question.

An analog signal is PCM formatted and transmitted using binary waveforms over a
channel that is bandlimited to 100 kHz. Assume that 32 quantization levels are used
and that the overall equivalent transfer function is of the raised cosine type with roll-off r = 0.6.

a. Find the maximum bit rate that can be used by this system without introducing ISI.

b. Find the maximum bandwidth of the original analog signal that can be
accommodated with these parameters.

(B. Sklar and F. Harris "Digital Communications: Fundamentals & Applications)

I read the answer from the book, and it states that R = Rs = 125 ksymbols/s = 125kbits/s.
However, this question states that there are 32 quantization levels used. According to my understanding, each symbol should be encoded with 5 bits and thus, the bit rate should be 125ksymbols/s * 5 = 625kbits/s.

Is my understanding correct? Why in this case the answer state that the symbol rate is equal to the bit rate?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It says "binary waveforms". You'll need the $32$ quantization levels for solving part b.

Comment: The _analog_ signal is sampled and then quantized using 32 levels. The _digital_ signal is binary. How many binary pulses are needed to transmit one sample from the analog signal?